# customHeaders on signature API

Tags: fine-uploader

I need to add some custom headers to the signature call made by FineUploder. My CoffeeScript looks like this:

```coffeescript
  options =
    chunking:
      enabled: true
    cors:
      allowXdr: true
    debug:    true
    iframeSupport:
      localBlankPagePath: "/assets/blank.html"
    ios:      false
    multiple: false
    request:
      endpoint:  "..."
      accessKey: "..."
      customHeaders:
        Accept: "application/vnd.keas_web+json;version=4, application/json, text/plain, */*"
        X-Something: "Something"
    resume:
      enabled: true
    retry:
      showButton: true
    signature:
      endpoint: "http://localhost:3001/api/s3/sign"
    uploadSuccess:
      endpoint: "..."
    validation:
      itemLimit: 5
      sizeLimit: 1000000

  $("#uploader").fineUploaderS3(options)
```

The signature.endpoint API is getting invoked, but the custom headers aren't getting sent. (I verified this not only in the server but in Chrome's network panel.)

Do I need to set the custom headers differently for the signature API call versus other calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sending custom headers in Fine Uploader S3 to your signature endpoint is not currently supported.  This was requested a week or so ago, and the ability to specify custom headers for all S3-related ajax requests to your local server will be available in Fine Uploader 3.9, which should release in a couple weeks.  You can see [feature request #956](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/956) for more details.

On an unrelated note, there are a few issues with your client-side code:

1. The `customHeaders` property of the `request` option is ignored in Fine Uploader S3 (as you probably figured out already)
2. Why are you setting `allowXdr` to "true", but not setting the `expected` property of the `cors` option to "true"?  If you are working in a cross-origin environment, you must set `cors.expected` to true as well.  In Fine Uploader S3, `cors.allowXdr` defaults to "true" anyway.  If your signature & uploadSuccess servers are on the same domain as the page hosting Fine Uploader, then there is no need to deal with the `cors` option anyway.
3. There is no `ios` option.  The `camera` option has an `ios` property, that defaults to "false".

Comment: I can work around the issue with custom headers not being passed to the signature URL, but it looks like they also aren't supported for `uploadSuccess.endpoint`.

Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.  This may have been a bit of an oversight when developing the S3 module.  It was quite a bit of work, so these types of issues were bound to surface.  As mentioned, the ability to do this will exist in 3.9.  William, I see you are a commercial license holder.  I'll send you an email with another option for you.